# react native how to import from third library by using "import"?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use SliderButton, I recently installed slider-button in my terminal,

```
npm install --save react-native-slider-button
```

and tried to import it, but somehow it did not work.

on website, I am supposed to write

```
var SliderButton = require("react-native-slider-button");
```

but my react-native is latest ver so i am guessing that I probably should not use require, how do I write code with using "import"?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `require` with `import` by placing the following at the top of your file:

```
import SliderButton from "react-native-slider-button"

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't really just "import" this particular component. It was written using an earlier implementation of JS called CommonJS which is used in NodeJS. React Native now uses ES6 for module management. The SliderButton Component is a little problematic. First, it uses the CommonJS module syntax inside the component itself, including loading React and React Native in ways that are no longer supported. So parts of this module would have to be rewritten to work with current versions of react native. You could roll back to a previous react native version that supports CommonJS, or you could modify the Component to use the ES6-style module importation.

Comment: oh ok, so i might be using different version then, could you tell me how I can write this code with using import? is it like this? import SliderButton from "react-native-slider-button"

Comment: The component itself needs to be rewritten since it extends the React Component class. If this is something you're not familiar with, I could probably bang it out sometime later this week.

Comment: thank you for the reply, after you explained it to me, I looked it up google and I think i got it. thank you~!!